# Matlab cellfun with differently-sized input arrays

Tags: matlab

How can I use `cellfun` (or appropriate alternative) when the input arrays are different sizes, and get all combinations of results (i.e., evaluated for the cross join of the arrays)?

This example uses a dummy function; the actual function is more complicated, so I'm looking for answers that call a custom function. Using Matlab R2018a, so I'm looking for an answer that is compatible with that.

```
a = 0:0.1:0.3; b = 100:5:120;

test = cellfun(@(x,y) myfunc(x,y,0), num2cell(a), num2cell(b));

function [result] = myfunc(i, j, k)
    % k is needed as fixed adjustment in "real life function"
    result = 0.1 * i + sqrt(j) + k;
end
```

The above code returns the following error:

```
Error using cellfun
All of the input arguments must be of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had size 4 in dimension 2. Input #3 has size 5
```

The expected output from this example is the "result" column below; i and j are shown for convenience.

| i | j | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 10 |
| 0.1 | 100 | 10.01 |
| 0.2 | 100 | 10.02 |
| 0.3 | 100 | 10.03 |
| 0 | 105 | 10.24695077 |
| 0.1 | 105 | 10.25695077 |
| 0.2 | 105 | 10.26695077 |
| 0.3 | 105 | 10.27695077 |
| 0 | 110 | 10.48808848 |
| etc | etc | etc |

Comment: `cellfun` doesn’t do that, but it would be trivial to write two nested loops to iterate over all combinations.

Comment: If the cell's contents are numbers you can use numerical vectors instead of cell arrays, and maybe exploit [implicit expansion](https://nhigham.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/) to [vectorize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) your function. But that totally depends on what the actual function has to do. Your dummy example function is not enough information

Comment: I was hoping for something without a loop; was initially thinking of manually expanding the vectors with something like [this Mathworks forum answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/433424-how-to-get-the-combinations-of-elements-of-two-arrays), so I was happy see @ Luis Mendo and @ Pursuit recommend bsxfun

Comment: “Hoping for something without a loop” Why? It has been at least 15 years that  MATLAB isn’t slow with loops any more. Is that fear of loops still around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is `bsxfun`. A worked example is below.

```
% You need a function with the correct number of inputs.
% With your sample, I would do something like this.
myfunc       = @(i,j,k) 0.1 * i + sqrt(j) + k;
myfunc_inner = @(i,j) myfunc(i,j,0);
%    Side not: using separate files for functions is more 
%    efficient, but makes for worse examples on stackoverflow

%Setting up the inputs    
a = 0:0.1:0.3;
b = 100:5:120;

%bsxfun, for two inputs, is called like this.
c = bsxfun(myfunc_inner, a', b)
```

`bsxfun` does the following:

- Expands scalar dimensions of the inputs so that they match
- Performs element-wise combinations of the inputs, using the provided function input

In this case, the result is:

```
c =
           10       10.247       10.488       10.724       10.954
        10.01       10.257       10.498       10.734       10.964
        10.02       10.267       10.508       10.744       10.974
        10.03       10.277       10.518       10.754       10.984
```

To get the input in the form you requested, simply run `c(:)`.

---

Historical note:

Back in the time-before-time, we had to use `bsxfun` more often. Now Matlab  expands single dimensions without notice when we perform simple operations on numbers. For example, I used to use the following style frequently:

```
a = [1 2 3];
b = [4 5 6];

c = bsxfun(@plus, a', b)
```

Whereas now we simply write:

```
c = a' + b
```

Comment: awesome answer, I didn't know about bsxfun, and the inner_func helper is very clever! it looks like it doesn't work with multiple output arguments? (which I didn't have in OP, just curious)

Comment: True, `bsxfun` does not work with multiple outputs. What format would you want the multiple outputs in?

Comment: Two arrays? something like `[result1, result2] = myfunc(i, j, k)` and adding a line to the OP function like `result2 = 0.1 * j + sqrt(i) - k;` for a simple MRE